# Reformating timestamps in python seaborn boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to reformat the timestamp labels of a `boxplot` created using `seaborn`, although the question probably applies to all `matplotlib` based graphs.

The x-axis of the graph is created as follows:

```py
pd.date_range("2021-01-01", periods=240, freq="H").time
```

The boxplot formats the x-axes labels as `'%H:%M:%S'`, but I wanted the format to be `'%H:%M'`.
I managed to achieve this by changing the index to a string format, as follows (dataframe is called `pvt`):

```py
pvt.index = [x.strftime('%H:%M') for x in pvt.index]
```

BUT my objective is to leave the dataframe untouched and to manage formatting within the plt functionality by reformatting the x-axis labels from `'%H:%M:%S'` to `'%H:%M'`. How can this be done?

Below you find the example code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import seaborn as sns

hours = 24 * 10 # 24 hours for 10 days
index = pd.date_range("2021-01-01", periods=hours, freq="H") # hourly intervals for 10 days
data = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(hours, 1)) # a random number for each hour
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['values'],index = index)
df['date']=df.index.date
df['time']=df.index.time
pvt = df.pivot(index='time',columns='date')
# pvt.index = [x.strftime('%H:%M') for x in pvt.index] I don't want to change the dataframe, I want to manage the formatting the graph
ax = sns.boxplot(data=pvt.T) # transpose as we want to study the distribution for each hour of the day
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Comment: In your example, you are generating `boxplot`, not `heatmap`

Comment: Yes, sorry, you are right. My original problem was indeed a heatmap, but a heatmap of random data is not so meaningful... ;-) I will amend the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import seaborn as sns
import datetime

hours = 24 * 10 # 24 hours for 10 days
index = pd.date_range("2021-01-01", periods=hours, freq="H") # hourly intervals for 10 days

data = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(hours, 1)) # a random number for each hour

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['values'],index = index)
df['date']=df.index.date
df['time']=df.index.time

time_lst=[datetime.time(i,0,0) for i in range(24)]

ax = sns.boxplot(data=df,x='time',y='values',order=time_lst) # you can generate the boxplot  without pivoting your dataframe

ax.set_xticklabels([x.strftime('%H:%M') for x in time_lst]) # here you adding formatted labels

plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```